# Using r.water.outlet of GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, watershed

I'm new to GIS - more so in GRASS GIS. I installed GRASS GIS 6.4.3svn in my Windows 7 machine. No problem in installation.

- Downloaded SRTM-Geotiff file
- Location, Mapset all o.k
- Used *r.in.gdal* to import SRTM file
- Filled the sinks using *r.terraflow*
- *Masked* the filled raster
- Zoomed the required region & set the computational region
- Ran *r.watershed* using *threshold=10000*
- Got drainge, basin, stream & visual rasters
- Visual rendering of rasters (drainge, basin, stream & visual) - o.k
- Different Watersheds (basins) displayed for entire area
- Zoomed stream raster to find lat/lon of mouth of river (cross checked with Google earth)
- Converted the lat/lon as decimal
- Ran *r.water.outlet* using *stream* as input & gave the lat/lon as easting & northing
- **Sadly the output display is blank**
- Rerun *r.water.outlet* - only a small dot in the lat/lon point. No delineation of watershed for the given easting & northing
- All the above procedures as per manuals
- Self learning of GRASS GIS - no formal training

How do I get the watershed (basin) for the given lat/lon?

Comment: Well friends, I'm answering my own question. The procedure I followed is almost correct.

The mistakes which I have done - hope it helps new comers like me...

 - Used *stream* raster instead of *drainage* - in r.water.outlet - **please be careful in the input**
 - Entered lat/lon with 2 digits after decimal - for accuracy **atleast 4 digits after decimal** is required.
 - Keep the *stream vector* displayed & *adjust the lat/lon* till you get watershed - by *gradual increase / decrease* of lat/lon.

Thanks to all .....

Comment: Important: no sink filling needed for r.watershed! It does least cost routing. Hence no need to use r.terraflow here, you can simplify your procedure.

Comment: Also, the input to r.water.outlet should be the **flow direction** raster (From r.watershed, the "drain=" output parameter).

Comment: Thanks to markusN & Micha for important & useful reply. Is it necessary to provide such a accurate easting & northing (4 digits after decimal)? Somewhere I saw, one GIS user provided just two digits after decimal & the watershed plotted nicely. Kindly enlighten me..

Comment: It doesn't matter how many digits after the decimal point. What matters is that the outlet point falls exactly on a stream. If the outlet points happens to fall exactly on a degree then you will not need any places after the decimal. But in most cases you probably should use at least 4 places, as you wrote.

Comment: Thanks Micha, is there any method available to demarcate watershed for a location other than stream? I mean, if I want to find out the watershed for a place, where no stream available but, sheet of water can flow (like a causeway / Irish bridge). Thanks....

Comment: I guess the answer above should go into the next box to resolve this question officially...

Comment: I have been following the discussion as I am having the same problem reported by Vishy. I created the Drainage and Stream raster. I gave as imput to the r.water.outlet command the Drainage raster but I can't find a point belonging to the Stream raster that can allow the calculation of the basins.
Is there a way to find the coordinates of any point that allows the visualization of the basins?
Thanks in advance to all.